# Gulp: Run multiple node scripts in parallel

Tags: node.js, gulp

I've got two server scripts (both are relying on socket.io; running on different ports).

I'd like to start both in parallel via gulp. But in addition I'd like to have a possibility to stop one of them. And maybe even access the console output of each script.

Is there any existing solution for this? Or would you even recommend using anything else than gulp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution in which I additionally start a mongoDB server:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

var processes = {server1: null, server2: null, mongo: null};

gulp.task('start:server', function (cb) {
    // The magic happens here ...
    processes.server1 = nodemon({
        script: "server1.js",
        ext: "js"
    });

    // ... and here
    processes.server2 = nodemon({
        script: "server2.js",
        ext: "js"
    });

    cb(); // For parallel execution accept a callback.
          // For further info see "Async task support" section here:
          // https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md
});

gulp.task('start:mongo', function (cb) {
    processes.mongo = child_process.exec('mongod', function (err, stdout, stderr) {});

    cb();
});

process.on('exit', function () {
    // In case the gulp process is closed (e.g. by pressing [CTRL + C]) stop both processes
    processes.server1.kill();
    processes.server2.kill();
    processes.mongo.kill();
});

gulp.task('run', ['start:mongo', 'start:server']);
gulp.task('default', ['run']);
```

Comment: I'm open to suggestions and willing to give the checkmark to better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`nodemon/foreverjs` is a good solution for not complicated cases, but they are not as scalable as [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) is. So, if you want a scalable and reliable solution I'd recommend to use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).
Also, it worth mentioning that pm2 daemonizes after start unlike `foreverjs/nodemon`. It could be *a bug or a feature* for you and generally depends on your needs.

```
pm2 start script1.js
pm2 start script2.js
pm2 status // show status of running processes
pm2 logs // tail -f logs from running processes
```